# Microsoft Teams app | Unable to open external application links provided in the OpenUri action targets for Connector Message Cards

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have created a custom Microsoft Teams app with a custom connector for sending notifications from our product JustCall. We are using MessageCard for sending actionable messages via Connector.
In the actionable messageCard format, we use OpenUri actions and its targets (default, Windows, iOS and Android) to open platform-specific JustCall application (outside the Microsoft Teams app) deep links from the sent notification.
From the Teams Android and web app, these targets work perfectly fine. But they do not seem to work from Windows and iOS Teams app. On iOS, when we click on the OpenUri action we receive an error message saying ***Invalid URL***, whereas on the Teams Desktop app, it redirects to the web browser i.e. uses the default target instead of the one specified for the windows.
Please refer to the attached
from iOS device for reference.
We are using the syntax as mentioned in the Microsoft Teams [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference#openuri-action). Please refer to the sample message card format along with the working deep links that we are using:

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "themeColor": "0076D7",
    "summary": "Test message by dev",
    "sections": [
        {
            "activityTitle": "Test message by dev",
            "activitySubtitle": "28th Aug 2023, 5:31pm",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "name": "Test Key 1",
                    "value": "Lorem Ipsum"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test key 2",
                    "value": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum"
                }
                
            ],
            "markdown": true
        }
    ],
    "potentialAction": [
        {
            "@type": "OpenUri",
            "name": "Call Contact via JustCall",
            "targets": [
                {
                    "os": "default",
                    "uri": "https://app.justcall.io/dialer?numbers=+15555551234"
                },
                {
                    "os": "iOS",
                    "uri": "justcall://app/call?number=+15555551234"
                },
                {
                    "os": "android",
                    "uri": "justcall://app/call?number=+15555551234"
                },
                {
                    "os": "windows",
                    "uri": "justcall:+15555551234"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is their any restriction from the Teams end that might be blocking the deep link access from iOS and windows devices?

We have tested our deep links for JustCall from other 3-third party apps like Slack. The links are working fine with the latest version of the JustCall app from all the devices.

**Expected Behaviour:** The deep links should be working from the iOS and Windows Teams app as per their documentation.

Comment: This issue is being tracked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1375764/while-using-microsoft-teams-connectors-messagecard. Please check the Microsoft QnA thread for further updates. Thank you.